# Tuleap : How to change my username

Tags: user-accounts, tuleap

I've been using Tuleap and I want to change my username. How can I do that, please? I've only worked out how to change my full name, not my username.

Answer (score 0):

A site admin can change your name in Admin > Search user widget > User